# How to enable antialiasing for QOpenGLWidget in QGraphicsView?

Tags: qt, qgraphicsview, qt5.4

I have added QOpenGLWidget to QGraphicsView (don't use setviewport) via QGraphicsProxyWidget:

```
QSurfaceFormat format= QSurfaceFormat();
format->setSamples(4); //<== widget show black screen if samples =4, 1 is ok but not antialiasing
m_glWidget->setFormat(format);

MyGraphicsProxyWidget* proxy= new MyGraphicsProxyWidget();
proxy->setWidget(m_glWidget);
//add to scene
scene->addItem(proxy);
```

I've tried some ways but not work:
glwidget show black screen if samples =4, but samples = 1 is ok but not antialiasing. 
So how to enable antialiasing for QOpenGLWidget (added by GraphicsproxyWidget) in QGraphicsView?

Any helps? Thanks!

Comment: Have you tried `view.setRenderHints(QPainter::Antialiasing)`?

Comment: yes, I've tried before (both of painter in glwidget and graphicsview) but not antialiasing (but still that glwidget if add to QMainwindow and set samples = 4, it works well)

Answer (score 5):

append beyond code to your main.cpp under qapplication initialization

```
QSurfaceFormat fmt;
fmt.setSamples(10); 
QSurfaceFormat::setDefaultFormat(fmt);
```

Comment: Just as a note, this is required to be BEFORE the widget or its parent are shown: e.g. For QOpenGLWidget, initializeGL is called in the main app.exec() loop, so too late.In my case, I did it in the widget constructor.

Comment: Can be required to call explicitely `glEnable(GL_MULTISAMPLE);` before each drawing. I experimented issues without doing that.