# How to enable multisampling Anti-Aliasing with QOpenGLWidget?

Tags: c++, qt, opengl, antialiasing

I have a QDockWidget that contains a QOpenGLWidget inside it.
I'm trying to set up AA in the GL viewport, but nothing I tried so far worked.

Right now I'm trying to set up the surface format in the widget's constructor, like so:

```
QSurfaceFormat format;
format.setRenderableType(QSurfaceFormat::OpenGL);
format.setProfile(QSurfaceFormat::CoreProfile);
format.setVersion(4, 1);    
format.setSamples(16);
setFormat(format);
```

Then, in the initializeGL function, I've added the line `glEnable(GL_MULTISAMPLE);`
However, it doesn't work. No Anti-Aliasing.
I tried [several](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28417423/how-to-enable-antialiasing-for-qopenglwidget-in-qgraphicsview) [other](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10971428/what-steps-are-necessary-to-enable-antialiasing-when-using-a-qpainter-on-a-qglwi) approaches, including [creating the GL context myself](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14474259/how-do-i-enable-multisampling-antialiasing-in-opengl-with-qt5) and setting the format on it or setting up application flags and the default surface format, but none of them worked either.

I'm quite at a loss here, and I'm probably missing something simple since the consensus points to format.setSamples(16); as the crucial element, but as I said, it doesn't work for me.

Any ideas what I'm doing wrong here?

Comment: Does your implementation actually *support* 16 samples? Have you tried 8 or 4? How do you even know that there is no antialiasing? Are you looking for the right *kind* of antialiasing?

Comment: @NicolBolas I've tried with other sample values, yes. I'm not sure what other kinds of anti-aliasing you're referring to, but no matter which value I try there's no visible change in the display